# how does POST happen from /users and not /users/new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i went through the default routes created by

resources :photos
over here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

im confused about:

```
    POST      /photos     create        create a new photo
```

when creating a new photo, isnt the POST happening from the /photos/new action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just quoting Mischa:
"There is no redirect and /photos/create is never called. When you submit your form on /photos/new a POST request to /photos is done. Then Rails' router makes sure the create action in your controller is executed."

that was the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

`/photos/new` action returns the form to create a new photo.
After you fill the required information and clicked create then
`/photos/create` is called.

Comment: There is no redirect and `/photos/create` is never called. When you submit your form on `/photos/new` a POST request to `/photos` is done. Then Rails' router makes sure the `create` action in your controller is executed.

Comment: Mischa is right i guess. i misunderstood the http method to be linked to the place from where its called. my bad. n thanks :)